# Filter rows whose columns are between two numbers from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, range, multiple-conditions

I have two data frames and I want to filter the first one by the second one using start and end.

Data frame 1 : singletons_bovis

| gene_id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WB0001 | 54 | 1500 |
| WB0002 | 5410 | 15246 |

Data frame 2 : singletons_elegans

| transcript_id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C55C2.5d | 2547 | 54826 |
| F12B6.1a.1 | 0 | 458 |

I want to keep the rows of singletons_bovis whose start is between start-250 of singletons_elegans and start+250 of singletons_elegans.
The same for end.

I tried this command :

```
df <- singletons_bovis %>% filter((start < singletons_elegans$start+250 & start > singletons_elegans$start-250) & (end > singletons_elegans$end-250 & end < singletons_elegans$end+250))
```

But it doesn't work...I don't know how to write that using dplyr. May someone knows how to write it?

Answer (score 1):

This may be done with a non-equi join.  In the latest dplyr version (`>= 1.1.0`), can use `join_by` to do this

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
singletons_elegans %>%
     mutate(start1 = start + 250, start2 = start - 250,
                end1 = end -250, end2 = end + 250) %>%
      inner_join(singletons_bovis, ., by = join_by(closest(start < start1), 
           closest(start > start2), closest(end > end1), closest(end < end2)))
```

---

Or use `powerjoin`

```
library(powerjoin)
 power_inner_join(singletons_bovis, singletons_elegans, by = 
   c(~ .x$start < (.y$start + 250) & .x$start > (.y$start - 250) & 
    .x$end > (.y$end - 250) & .x$end < (.y$end + 250) ))
```

Comment: I tried the second solution. It works. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the `powerjoin` way can be replaced with `by = c(~ abs(.x$start - .y$start) < 250) & abs(.x$end  - .y$end) < 250)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two easy data frames.

```
singletons_bovis
#   start stop
# 1     1    5
# 2     1    9
# 3     2    4
# 4     1    8
# 5     7    8

singletons_elegans
#   start stop
# 1     1    4
# 2     5    6
# 3     2    4
# 4     2    7
# 5     1    3
```

You can do this without `library`s.

```
singletons_bovis[singletons_bovis$start >= singletons_elegans$start - 2.5 & 
                   singletons_bovis$stop <= singletons_elegans$stop + 2.5, ]
#   start stop
# 1     1    5
# 3     2    4
# 4     1    8
```

---

*Data:*

```
m <- 10
set.seed(42)
singletons_bovis <- as.data.frame(t(replicate(m, sort(sample(1:9, 2)))))
singletons_elegans <- as.data.frame(t(replicate(m, sort(sample(1:9, 2)))))
names(singletons_bovis) <- names(singletons_elegans) <- c('start', 'stop')
```